# Player cant move more than 1 time (in the same direction) Unity2d Android

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, 2d

• UNITY2D Game For Android Mobiles

---

Hello guys..
So I created a player who should move only vertically..
so i created 2 buttons (up and down)
that should control him

when i tap the up button my player moves up and everythings work well (for now) but when i release the up button and want to tap it a second time it doesnt work ( the player doesnt move in that direction anymore)
( unless i tap down button before )

///// the same thing for the 2 buttons (Up And Down)

this is my player script

/////

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Player : MonoBehaviour
{

    public float playerSpeed;
    private Rigidbody2D rb;
    private Vector2 playerDirection;

    private float verticalMove;
    private bool moveUp;
    private bool moveDown;

    //public static bool shoot = false;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        moveDown = false;
        moveUp = false;

    }

    public void pointerDownLota()
    {
        moveDown = true;
    }
    public void pointerUpLota()
    {
        moveDown = false;
    }
    public void pointerDownFog()
    {
        moveUp = true;
    }

    public void pointerUpFog()
    {
        moveUp = false;
    }



    void Movement()
    {
        
        if (moveDown && !moveUp)
        {
            verticalMove = -playerSpeed;


        }
        else if (moveUp && !moveDown)
        {

            verticalMove = playerSpeed;


        }
        else
        {
            verticalMove = 0;


        }
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        float directionY = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");
        playerDirection = new Vector2(0, directionY).normalized;

        
    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
       Movement();
       rb.velocity = new Vector2(rb.velocity.x , verticalMove);
    }
}
```

Please I Need help

I tried many tutos
but i am a beginner so i couldnt found a solution

can anyone help me ?

[How I call the button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zhV3p.jpg)

Comment: thats a mighty odd way to do it but it depends how you're calling all these things

Comment: i updated the question, and added an image showing how the down button  was called